# Couldn't for present impossibility

Tags: grammar

*You have just had dinner. You can't be hungry now.*
can we use couldn't in this sentence instead of can't?

Comment: No, it's not natural. Stick with "can", which is the normal form to convey such meanings.

Answer (score 1):

yes, although the sentence I regularly use with my teenage child is "You *couldn't possibly* be hungry again!"